# J programming language (E)BNF

Tags: grammar, bnf, j, ebnf, ll-grammar

I'm writing a paper for my Programming Languages and Compilers course about the J programming language. Since it's a relatively unknown (*but interesting*) programming language, I'm having trouble finding the right documentation and information regarding the formal grammar of J in (E)BNF, some open-source implementations of J, especially lexical analyzers and parsers.

Does anyone know of an accurate source for an **(E)BNF** for the J programming language? If so, is that an **LL grammar** and can it be "put through" a parser generator?

Comment: Try asking the [j programming forum](http://www.jsoftware.com/mailman/listinfo/programming). Some people there will know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(E)BNF is a notation technique for context-free grammars. But J is a context-sensitive language [1,2]. J's parsing rules are listed in the Dictionary II. E [3].

References:

1. https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/Language_FAQ/J_BNF
2. http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/general/2005-July/023632.html
3. https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dicte.htm

Answer (score 4):

J uses a parsing table based on a stack that evaluates the sentence as soon as it has enough information. The best source for this, I believe, are Chapters 38 and 39 of Henry Rich's "J for C programmers". You need to be able to be comfortable with tacit J to make the most of this, but it should serve as a good introduction to the parser.
https://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/parsing_and_execution_i.htm#_Toc191734584 https://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/parsing_and_execution_ii.htm#_Toc191734586

Another source for understanding J's evaluation is the `trace` verb, which can be found in the trace script located for recent versions of J. eg.  for `j901` in `j901/addons/general/misc/trace.ijs`  This gives a hands on experience that will step through a J sentence and list the rules implemented and the current state of the stack.

If you have downloaded the addons for J this would already be available in your installation.

```
    load '~addons/general/misc/trace.ijs'
  trace '(+/ % #) 5 7 3 4 5 2' NB. returns the trace for the average of list of numbers
 --------------- 3 Adverb -----
 +
 /
 +/
 --------------- 5 Trident ----
 +/
 %
 #
 +/ % #
 --------------- 8 Paren ------
 (
 +/ % #
 )
 +/ % #
 --------------- 0 Monad ------
 +/ % #
 5 7 3 4 5 2
 4.33333
 ==============================
4.33333
```